# Entity Framework Core database migration in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to migrate a database (the database was already created beforehand) through the startup of an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app. I created the migration by enabling migrations in the Visual Studio Package Manager Console:

```
enable-migrations
```

And then created a migration:

```
Add-Migration TestTable –Context MyDbContext
```

`TestTable` creates a simple table that I use to test the migration.

I want to be able to migrate the database on startup, without the need to use the Visual Studio Package Manager Console, without the need to use the `update-database` command.

I have tried this:

```
var migrationAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"),
        sql => sql.MigrationAssembly(migrationAssembly))));
```

I get no errors, but the table never gets created. I tried simple crud operations on the table but they throw error because the table doesn't exist, also I checked in the SQL Server Object Explorer and the table isn't there.

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this code

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, DataContext dataContext)
{
    // migrate any database changes on startup (includes initial db creation)
    dataContext.Database.Migrate();

    ...
 }
```

here's the reference link:
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/12/27/aspnet-core-automatic-ef-core-migrations-to-sql-database-on-startup